# Converting call from a .txt into a string c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read from a text file and then count the number of occurences of each word and then export the results to a different text file. I'm only allowed to use loops and arrays for this assignment. I'm just looking for a slight push in the right direction, primarily in the beginning of the code. It's not compiling correctly!

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>


void put(string word, string words[], int counts[], int & size)

{
 int w;
 for (w = 0; w < size && word >= words[w]; w++);
 if (w >= size) {
 words[w] = word;
 counts[w] = 1;
 ++size;
}
else if (word < words[w]) {

for (int i = size - 1; i >= w; i--) {
 words[i + 1] = words[i];
 counts[i + 1] = counts[i];
}
words[w] = word;
counts[w] = 1;
++size;
}
else {
counts[w] = counts[w] + 1;
}
}

int main()
{
 int word;

 ifstream input("input.txt");
 ofstream chout("charcount.txt");
 ofstream wout("wordscounts.txt");


 int inputSize = sizeof(input) / sizeof(string);
 int counts[100];
 const int MAX = 100;
 string words[MAX];
 int wordsSize = 0;


 while (input >> word) {
  put(input[word], words, counts, wordsSize);
 }



 wout << "       Word  Frequency" << endl;

for (word = 0; word < inputSize; ++word) {
 wout << setw(10) << words[word] << setw(4) << counts[word] << endl;
 }




chout.close();
wout.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
put(input[word], words, counts, wordsSize);
```

You are trying to index into an `ifstream`. This is simply not allowed. The compiler (g++ 4.8.4) said:

```
no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::ifstream {aka std::basic_ifstream<char>}’ and ‘int’)
```

Comment: It's the professor's example unfortunately. I'll post what he said. 

     int word;
     string input[] = { ... }
      for (word = 0; word < inputSize; ++word) {
     put (input[word], words, counts, wordsSize);
      }
      with:

       string word;
       ifstream input (arg[1]);
       while (input >> word) 
       put (input[word], words, counts, wordsSize);

Comment: @ZackMcCoskey: so there are `string input[]` and `ifstream input`? Please post the complete code in your question.